# Bibliography style does not change (Elsevier)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I need to put the bibliography style in my paper like below:

> Li, X., Heckman, N. E.(2003). Local linear extrapolation. Journal of Nonparametric Statistics 15, 565–578.

(so called author-year style, year in the parentheses and so forth)-

So I found a file for this style and put it in the style folder of Endnote. 
And read my references again and export to Mendeley by XML file.
In Mendeley I also choose that style and export as `.bib` file.
Until now, those two programs show the result I want to have.

But it does not change style according to that style in LaTeX.

My LaTeX code is:

```
\documentclass[authoryear]{elsarticle}
\begin{document}

 ..........as \citep{Li2003}. .................

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{n8}
\end{document}
```

But this only gives:

> Li, X., Heckman, N. E., 2003. Local linear extrapolation. Journal of Nonparametric Statistics 15 (4-5), 565–578.

The year is not in parentheses and other parts are different.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style should be used for papers submitted to Elsevier journals that employ the author-year citation call-out style. However, it is not a universal bibliography style. If your formatting requirements are different -- e.g., you need parentheses around the publication year -- you should probably not be using the `elsarticle-harv` bibliography style to begin with. Who told you to use `elsarticle-harv`?

Comment: @Mico From the author guide of Elsevier. There is a journal using this style, year in the parenthesis. http://open.mendeley.com/use-citation-style/international-journal-of-forecasting

Comment: The link you've provided works only if one has something called "Mendeley Desktop", which I do not have and which I do not plan on getting. Is there a non-proprietary site from which this information might be obtained from? Anyway, is the journal you're planning to submit a paper to an Elsevier journal? Your write-up isn't clear on this subject.

Comment: I've figured out in the meantime that the journal you're interested in is the *International Journal of Forecasting*. It is an Elsevier journal. Its website says that authors who consider submitting their papers using LaTeX should use the `elsarticle` document class and the `elsarticle-harv` BibTeX bibliography style. I'd follow these guidelines and not be worried one bit if some other site provides erroneous information about the formatting requirements. If you feel like it, you can write to the website that provides the incorrect information and ask them to apply the necessary corrections.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Already I sent an email! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a right '.bst' file for this journal. 
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/newapa

I hope this helps other researchers having the same problem or likely having that problem.

Also, I think this file can apply to other journals of Elsevier.